# Openvino-opencv videocapture abnormal behaviour

Tags: python, opencv, openvino

I have been using IP camera's rtsp stream for video capturing. For capturing and display,I've found `openvino-opencv` is almost 10x faster than system `python-opencv`. BUT some abnormal things is going on which doesn't make sense to me:

Average time taken by `openvino-opencv` to read and display image is `0.01 sec approx.`except every once in a while (approxly after every 250 frame) it takes `4.5 sec approx`.

**NOTES**:

````
CAMERA MODEL: FLIR AX8
CAMERA FRAME_RATE = 30
Average time taken by system-python to read and display is 0.11
I tested with UCAM, both performs similar
I tested with static video, system-python runs faster.```
````

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the IP camera has some sort of buffering to avoid a non-continuous streaming.

I would recommend to match your consuming frames speed to the IP camera framerate and that shouldn't be a problem anymore.

Comment: i mean yes, there is a chance of buffering but since it is running smoothly on system python ,I am guessing we are facing some-other problems. May be dependency issues.